# Split a file using Azure Data Factory based on delimiter

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm very new to ADF, and I'm kinda stuck with the following use case:

I want to split a big file into multiple smaller files based on a delimiter. There will be a delimiter after some rows. For example, following is the input file content:

```
row1content
row2content
row3content
-----
row4content
row5content
-----
row6content
row7content
row8content
row9content
-----
row10content
row11content
row12content
```

Here `-----` is the delimiter on which I want to split a file into multiple smaller files as output, and name them like MyFile1, MyFile2, MyFile3, MyFile4 and so on, such that their content will be as follows(split based on the delimiter):

MyFile1:

```
row1content
row2content
row3content
```

MyFile2

```
row4content
row5content
```

MyFile3:

```
row6content
row7content
row8content
row9content
```

MyFile4:

```
row10content
row11content
row12content
```

I'm trying to achieve it using Data flows in ADF.
The source and destination of input/output files will be azure blob storage.
It'll be really helpful if someone can point me to a direction or a source from where I can proceed further.

Comment: What is the source / sink file format you are using ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT I've just chosen DelimitedText(csv) both as source and sink.